# Create Selectlist with separator in Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, selectlist

I'm trying to build a select list that will contain some prioritised values, then a separator, and then the rest of the values. I need to do this in a Html Helper, as I will get the values that will be prioritised and the rest of the values from different sources.

Sample of what I want to accomplish:

```
EUR
GBP
USD
---
SEK
ZAR
.
.
.
```

I also wanna make sure that the separator is not possible to select. If I do this straight in the html, I've manage to do this, but I haven't manage to disable the separator when doing this thru the helper. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: When an option gets rendered out, it is selectable. The default, simple HTML dropdown control is very limited in its options. You will have to resort to some kind of JavaScript to prevent the selection clientside but I am unaware of such a script - just pointing you in a possible direction.

Comment: I think you are going to have to right your own helper to do what you want...

Comment: Or just combine your two sources of values with the seperator and add a JavaScript-call to "onchange" like "new with {.onchange="MyJSFunction"} which checks for the separator and undoes the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up doing creating a html helper method that takes my two list, and for each item creates a new Tag of "option" type, and add it to a select list. That way I can add attributes, such as "disabled="disabled"" and so on.

It's not neat, it's not tidy. To be honest, it's kind of aweful code, and I would love to have a better way to do it. However, at the moment short of time to complete my task, so ended up doing this way:

```
var fullList = new StringBuilder();

var selectList = new TagBuilder("select");
selectList.Attributes.Add("name", "currencies");
selectList.Attributes.Add("id", "selectCurrency");

foreach (var currency in currencies)
{
    var option = new TagBuilder("option") {InnerHtml = currency.Id};
    option.Attributes.Add("value", currency.Id);
    fullList.AppendLine(option.ToString());
}

var separator = new TagBuilder("option") { InnerHtml = "-------" };
separator.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
fullList.AppendLine(separator.ToString());

selectList.InnerHtml = fullList.ToString();
```

If you have a better way, please let me know, and I'll might be able to revisit this task later on for some refactoring, and would love to have a good way to do it then.